# file not having end line and " at first column and last column

Tags: sql-server, csv, bcp

I am trying to export of table in csv file by using bcp command in microsoft sql server.

Below is the table sample data

```
Table name : XYZ
col1      col2      col3
abcd,inc. USD,inc   1234
pqrs,inc  USD,inc   6789
stuv,inc  USD,inc   0009
```

There is comma in column values as above.

I have written .fmt file like below:

```
test.fmt

13.0 
3  
1 SQLCHAR 0 4000 "\",\"" 1  col1 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
2 SQLCHAR 0 4000 "\",\"" 2  col2 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
3 SQLCHAR 0 4000 "\r\n" 3   col3 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Below is command I am using:

```
DECLARE 
@V_BCP_QUERY VARCHAR(4000),
@V_BCP_OUTPUT_FILE VARCHAR(1500),
@V_BCP_FORMAT_FILE VARCHAR(1500),
@V_BCP_COMMAND VARCHAR(4000)
begin

SET @V_BCP_QUERY='"SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM TABS..XYZ"'

SET @V_BCP_OUTPUT_FILE='"D:\OUTPUT.csv"'

SET @V_BCP_FORMAT_FILE='"D:\test.fmt"'

SET @V_BCP_COMMAND='bcp '+@V_BCP_QUERY+' queryout '+@V_BCP_OUTPUT_FILE+' -f '+@V_BCP_FORMAT_FILE+' -T -S "DEV-CR"'

EXECUTE Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell  @V_BCP_COMMAND

end
```

I am getting below data in OUTPUT.csv file:

```
abcd,inc.","USD,inc","1234
pqrs,inc","USD,inc","6789
stuv,inc","USD,inc","0009
```

there is no " at start of line and end of line.
Also when I open this in excel then all rows are coming in a single line

my requirement is to export file in csv file.

Kindly help

Comment: This is expected, you are defining your delimiter as `","`, and delimiters don't go at the start or end of each line. `bcp` doesn't support text identifiers, so you would be better off using a tool that does, or using a delimiter that doesn't appear in your data. Maybe a pipe (`|`) would be better choice, for example.

Comment: The fact you are using `xp_cmdshell` to call `bcp` that then calls SQL Server is even more "hacky" in my opinion. Use an actual ETL tool, rather than the method you are using.

Comment: I need to add this code snippet in stored procedure

Comment: Don't use the bcp Utility. It doesn't support delimited file data that includes quotes, commas or newlines despite RFC4180 having been a thing for 17 years already. If you need to export data containing embedded quotes, commas or newlines consider external tools such as PowerShell's `Export-Csv` cmdlet.

Comment: Why do you "need" an export process in a stored procedure? Why not use a different, more suitable, tool?

Comment: Here I am upload .csv file in sp then doing some process with uploaded data and generating .csv file of processed data

Comment: Definitely sounds like a case for an ETL tool that can *upload* the data, call a procedure to generate the data in the needed format and then consume that data and *export* it. T-SQL is wrong tool for this end-to-end solution. SSIS, which is part of SQL Server, would easily be able to achieve this, for example. YOu could use a Dataflow task for the import, and then another for the export, where the export uses a procedure that produces a dataset as the data source.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server studio management, any sample code to achieve my requirement and I can't ask client to allow me use ETL tool for this task, could you please help me with the tool that I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hack a solution together - but using the correct tool for the job would be much easier and better in the long run.

Instead of using BCP to output individual columns, create a single column formatted with your desired result:

```
SELECT quotename(concat_ws(',', quotename(col1, char(34)), quotename(col2, char(34)), quotename(col3, char(34)), char(34)) 
  FROM yourTable
```

This will give you a single column in your output - with double-quotes around the whole string, double-quotes around each column, concatenated with the '.' separator.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's ugly, but it's simple, quick and gets it done.

```
SELECT '"' + col1 + '",' +
        '"' + col2 + '",' +
        '"' + col3 + '"'
FROM Table
```

Comment: I used like below but still " is not coming:


SET @V_BCP_QUERY='"SELECT ''"''+col1+''"'',''"''+col2+''"'',''"''+col3+''"'' FROM TABS..XYZ"'

Comment: I think what you want it this: SET @V_BCP_QUERY='"SELECT ''"''+col1+''","''+col2+''","''+col3+''"'' FROM TABS..XYZ"'